# How to update date using drawString in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using WindowsForms and I draw the graphic and want to appear Date every in every step of my program. For example, graphic changes every day.
So my graphic is ok, but I can't change my date text message.
I'm using AddDays, but I can't put this in a loop or something.

```
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 02, 02); // Or whatever
DateTime dt2 = dt.AddDays(1);
string sqqq = dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Graphics g4 = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g4.DrawString(sqqq, drawFont, drawBrush, lol2, kek2);
```

I changed my code to this:

```
    Graphics g4 = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 02, 02); // Or whatever
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        DateTime dt2 = dt.AddDays(1);

        string sqqq = dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        g4.DrawString(sqqq, drawFont, drawBrush, lol2, kek2);
        dt = dt2;
    }
```

and it updates date, but now in every step my previous date overrides new date. It puts on top of each other. How to erase previous text drawing?

Comment: Stop using CreateGraphics(), start using the Paint event.  Call its Invalidate() method to get a repaint, typically with a timer's Tick event.

Comment: So, in addition to the non-persistent graphics and leaking resources (Font and brush) where is the issue? The date string?? Knowing when to do the drawing? (timer.Tick) What is _in every step of my program_ ??

Comment: So I have "Solve" button in my code, like iteration. And I want to update my data with every pressing of "Solve" button

Comment: So  add an pictureBox1.Invalidate() to the button_click. And, of course, do the drawstring in the pictureBox1.Paint code using the e.Graphics object there !

Comment: In Winforms, it would be better to layer a Label control with a transparent background over top of the image, and update the label.

Comment: Why don't you do what Hans and I told you?? Your answer was the exact opposite.. And what was that crazy loop supposed to achieve??

Comment: I'm new with this. Can only use CreateGraphics()